# Setting image in app.xaml depending on platform

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I have been trying to set icon in my application based on images in the app.xaml
I have tried the following and they do not work:

usage in my page   Icon="{StaticResource MyImageKey}">

```
<ImageSource x:Key="MyImageKey" >
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                            iOS="MyImage.jpg"
                            Android=""/>
        </ImageSource>



        <OnPlatform x:Key="MyImageKey" 
                    x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
            <On Platform="iOS">"MyImage.png"</On>
            <On Platform="Android">""</On>
        </OnPlatform>
```

can you point me in the right direction?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need add style in App resource like below :

```
<Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>

            <OnPlatform x:Key="MyImageKey" 
                      x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
                      iOS="contact.png"
                      Android="contact.png"
                      WinPhone="contact.png" />
       </ResourceDictionary>
       </Application.Resources>
```

Now you can use like below :

```
 <Image  Source="{StaticResource MyImageKey}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply but the code is already within resource dictionary in the app.xaml

Comment: Hi unfortunately that does not work either.You just used the deprecated way of doing the same.It might be a bug!!